# Dropdown selection doesnt change div content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get the content inside the div to change when I choose a different option from the dropdown menu. I had tabs inside the div before that worked, but they looked ugly so i ditched them for a dropdown menu instead. I'll be having the dropdown menu reference a map or grid the user can go through later on when i get this working.

Working Code: http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/aOJLqm

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
      <div class="ibox-title">
        <h5>Elements Map </h5>
        <div class="ibox-tools">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-purple" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Views
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li class="active" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#1">Map</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#2">List</a></li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Reset All</button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Element Map</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Are you sure?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Element Map</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="collapse-link">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ibox-content">
        <div class="active" id="1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt
          condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet
          vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet, charetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.
        </div>
        <div id="2">
          Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac
          orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue. Secondo sed ac orci
          quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .btn-green {
    background-color:#33CC33;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-blue {
    background-color:#3333FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-purple {
    background-color:#CC00FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-dropdown-style {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin: 14px 5px 5px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    background: #1ab394;
}

.nav-dropdown-style:hover {
  background: #199d82;
}
```

Comment: Do you consider writing js code to do this? It would be relatively easy :)

Comment: using javascript would make this a lot easier. You could search the change function for dropdowns and hide and show divs accordingly

Comment: i was considering using js but I'm not really that familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to write Javascript, this solution would work:

```
// Get all list options
var listOptions = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a');

// Attach "click" event
listOptions.click(function(ev) {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  // Find divs with content
  var divToShow = $(href);
  var contentDivs = divToShow.parent().find('.content');

  contentDivs.removeClass('active');
  divToShow.addClass('active');
});
```

I adjusted code a bit. Codepen is available right here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbMeoK. Please note that I made small changes to CSS too.

Comment: Thank you It works but I'm getting an issue with the rest of my content on the page. I have more that one div on the webpage and about 3 of those have a dropdown that is supposed to do the same. Everyone of them is contentless now, also when i choose an option from the dropdown it drags the screen down to it.

Comment: Notice use of "active" class. Only content with "active" class is shown, so you have to add "active" to div with content shown by default (please look closely at added CSS classes). And I would suggest adding more descriptive classes/ids to differentiate between each group. One more thing - for this example to work, each id of the content div should be different. As for the dropdown - UL and button should be closed in one "div" tag e.g. <div class="dropdown">(Your button and dropdown list here)</div>

Comment: I found some old code from the tabs that were messing with it, so they appear by default by now. When i select from the down down it still clears all the other divs. I did have the dropdown and list in its own div but it seems to push all the other buttons that are supposed to be beside it, below it. I updated the codepen with all the page code so you can see what im talkign about. http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/aOJLqm

Comment: This is adjusted codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdqaYr. As for buttons - you can add "float: left" param to them. Please look carefully at changes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Szyb, you gave me more than i asked for. I marked your answer correct! I'm still having issues getting Treatment, Efficiency, and Summary to appear (as they are just blank), but I'll hopefully figure it out myself.
Thanks :)

Comment: I fixed it, I wasn't referencing my classes properly, anyways thanks again :)